# Jpa OneToMany not persist child

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I've trouble on persistence of OneToMany field. These are two simplified classes
I'm using to make test.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
...
private String name;
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
...
}

public class PhoneNumber implements Serializable {
...
private String phoneNumber;
...
@ManyToOne()
private User  user;
...
}
```

So I want to do this:

```
User u = new User();
PhoneNumber p = new PhoneNumber();
u.setName("Alan");
u.getPhoneNumbers.add(p);
```

But when I persist the user u the phoneNumber child is not automatically persisted.
In OO way, I only need to do a one to many composition.

I use EclipseLink.

Many thanks to all for your hints.

Comment: It's kinda strange - such an example works fine in my case (EclipseLink). At the end you do just EntityManager#persist(u) ?
How do you know the value is not persisted - checked in the database or queried the entity somehow? Did you try flushing the EntityManager?

Answer (score 3):

You need to establish the relationship in both directions. Add `p.setUser(u)` to your code:

```
User u = new User();
PhoneNumber p = new PhoneNumber();
u.setName("Alan");
u.getPhoneNumbers.add(p);
p.setUser(u);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have to set both directions in order just to persist the PhoneNumber entity?

Comment: @Pedro If it is a bidirectional relationship (as shown in the code fragment of the question): Yes.

Comment: is it because the PhoneNumber is an invert side of the relationship?
I've successfully persisted the structure talked above without setting the second side of the relationship. The PhoneNumeber.user is set to null, but it's persisted successfully. 

Take a look at the JPA 2.0 spec 3.2.4 "Bidirectional relationships between managed entities will be persisted based on references held by the owning side of the relationship. It is the developer responsibility to keep the in-memory references held on the owning side and those held on the inverse side consistent with each other when they change"

Comment: Ok, I understand, so after calling persist(u) everything is ok in the database but the in-memory references are wrong, right? I am not sure. Didn't try it with the above code but I remember from one of my projects the same behavior as reported in the question and the problem was solved by adding the inverse relationship as shown in my answer. Hm...

Comment: no, after calling persist(u) both - the database AND the in-memory representations are 'wrong'. By 'wrong' I mean that there is no reference from PhoneNumber to User. In DB and in in-memory it's just 'null'. What I want to say is this situation doesn't prevent the persistence of the child element (PhoneNumber). It's properly added to the database and can be fetched using the EntityManager. I'm just not sure why the OP code doesn't work in his case...